# parseJSON and echo json_encode($array) - error, if php script warning

Tags: php, jquery, json

I use a Jquery script with parseJSON, like `data = $.parseJSON(json);`

It gets the result from a PHP script by `echo json_encode($array);`

If there goes something wrong in the PHP script, `data` gets also the warning from PHP like:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database...
```

That´s the reason why the jquery script shows in the browser console:

> VM76:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 3

How can I do it, that `data` doesn´t get the warnings from PHP? Or what is a good solution for this problem?

Comment: Please show your entire code.

Comment: You can ... a) fix the problem, so you no longer get errors in PHP ... or b) turn of error reporting in PHP, and keep on making mistakes.

Comment: @adeneo, thanks. Solution is not what i search for, because first i want to know and show, that is there an error.

"turn of error reporting in PHP" I had also considered. But is there no other solution?

Comment: Well, no, either you fix the error so it no longer throws an error message, or you turn of the messages, and still have an error. What other options could there possibly be ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just hide the PHP warnings with by adding:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

after the `<?php` tags. This should completely hide them so even when you get a response from PHP there wont be any errors on the client side